# Is event.pageX/Y Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I mean, going beyond the philosophical part that says "Jquery is Javascript too", I'm wondering why I can only find [Jquery event.pageX/Y descriptions](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_pagex.asp) but still be able to use a code like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show_coords(event)
{
  var x=event.pageX;
  var y=event.pageY;
  alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p onmousedown="show_coords(event)">Click this paragraph, 
and an alert box will alert the x and y coordinates 
of the mouse pointer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please tell me a reason why you’re getting your JavaScript knowledge from W3Schools. Here’s a more reliable source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: will get better information reading the API docs. Note that jQuery normalizes numerous properties cross browser. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Those properties are part of the native `MouseEvent`: [pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX), [pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY). No jQuery needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event attributes are indeed part of the DOM specs. These are two pertaining references:

- [W3C UI Events Specification (DOM Events Level 3)](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/)
- [MouseEvent object (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)